# Why we don't define the norm of operator $A$ as $\inf\limits_{||u||=1}||Au||$?

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, soft-question, normed-spaces

I always understand the norm of operator as the supreme multiple of the operator 'stretching' vector. But I think the multiple of operator compressing vector is same important.

Why we don't define  the norm of operator $A$ as $\inf\limits_{||u||=1}||Au||$?

What is I think :  first , it will dissatisfy triangle inequality of norm .Then, the norm can't induce a metric. But I really can't  realize the important of triangle inequality. Why we can't use a inverse triangle inequality to define metric ?

Comment: Also $\|A\|$ can be zero even if $A$ is not zero.

Comment: @Shalop  Yes,  I miss it .I think I should use $\inf\limits_{||Au||=1}\frac{1}{||u||}$. I don't know whether there will be another trouble ,if so .

Comment: If $\|{\cdot}\|$ dont have the porperties of a norm, as the triangle inequality, then it isnt a norm or a distance function. Take a look at [semimetrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Semimetrics).

Comment: The point is that any norm induces a topology on a given vector space. In order for this to be true, the norm needs to satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @lanse7pty: This is bascially $1/\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$, if the inverse $A^{-1}$ exists (and is bounded).